# Cloning attributes of one object to the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models Content and ContentType. Each Content (class not object) has its associated ContentType and ContentType basically holds some attributes that could be set using online form, which then can be used in the views to show/hide some of the content objects attributes.

After creating a new Content object (ex: @c = Content.new) I could retrieve the associated ContentType using:

class Content
 def content_type
  @content_type ||= ContentType.find_by_name(self.class.to_s)
 end
end

I could then query the ContentType attributes using @c.content_type.xxx but is there any way to directly access the ContentType attributes as if they are @c attributes without using the method_missing option. Basically instead of doing @c.content_type.has_title? I would like to ask @c.has_title?. Is there any way to clone the ContentType attributes onto @c?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate method

```
has_one :user
delegate :name, :name=, :email, :email=, :to => :user
```

This is at least somewhat better, as the ContentType can be hidden.

Also you can pass an `:allow_nil => true` option that saves you from pesky "Cant call nil.xxx" errors if the ContentType can be nil as well.